# Calculating angular distance via python atan2()

Tags: python

I need a function to calculate the shortest angular distance from an object in 2D space (x,y,theta) to a point.
So far I have:

```
def ang_distance(x1,y1,theta,x2,y2):
    ang_distance = atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) - theta
    return ang_distance
```

The problem is: theta ranges from -pi to pi, and atan2 also returns from -pi to pi, but i need the values to be the shortest angular distance.

So for example if theta = pi/2, and point x2,y2 is in 3rd quadrant, function will return longer angular distance...

Any suggestions on how do I change the function?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to add/subtract some multiple of `2 * pi` so that the angle is always between `-pi` and `pi`:

```py
def ang_distance(x1,y1,theta,x2,y2):
    angle = atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) - theta
    angle = angle - 2 * math.pi * math.floor(0.5 + angle / (2 * math.pi))
    return angle
```

Minor aside: I changed the variable name to `angle` rather than use the same name as the function (which will work ok, but is a bit confusing).

You could also use `round(...)` instead of `math.floor(0.5 + ...)`.